# regular expression for this string to extract the value

Tags: c#, java, html, regex

```
 <input > [ <input type="hidden" value="263" />First Name] [kdkgh[ <br /> <input 567> ag [<input type="hidden" value="264" />Last Name] dg input value="345"
```

i want to find the value `263` and  `First Name`     inside the  `[]`   and `264` and `Last Name` from the 2nd `[]` using regular expression , what would be the regular expression for this findings ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the source of this somewhat unusual markup? Is this valid html?

Comment: Is this line an example of a *complete* input for the matcher or just a smaller part? And do really don't care if the answer is for c# or java?

Comment: its a part of html tag, it will be generate automatically and i have to retrieve the value and name here for example "<input type="hidden" value="263" />First Name]" the value is :  263 and name is : First Name

Comment: @fean you really ought to fix whatever is giving you this ridiculous text/markup format.

Comment: As @DisgruntledGoat says, if you are in control of whatever is producing this markup then fix that rather than trying to come up with a regex solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't think you should do this* (see your comments). But try something like...

```
<input type="hidden" value="(.*?)" \/>(.*?)\]
```

[Example here](http://rubular.com/r/NHN3MTY7dm)

Answer (score 1):

```
        const string TestData =
            " <input > [ <input type=\"hidden\" value=\"263\" />First Name] [kdkgh[ <br /> <input 567> ag [<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"264\" />Last Name] dg input value=\"345\" ";
        var r = new Regex(@"\[\s*<input type=""hidden"" value=""([^\]]+)"" />([^\]]+)\]");
        var matches = r.Matches(TestData);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", matches[0].Groups[1].Value, matches[0].Groups[2].Value);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", matches[1].Groups[1].Value, matches[1].Groups[2].Value);
```

You could try something like that though it will fail if there is spaces somewhere else or if your string values contain "]"

Answer (score 0):

That markup looks crazy, but this will find the matches you're after:

```
\[.+?value="(\d+)"\s/>([^]]+)]
```